# Vue3 reactive and encapsulation

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, encapsulation, vue-reactivity

I am new to Vue and I am currently using Vue3.  As a learning exercise, I am making a simple login plugin and it is going well. I am using reactive() with an instance of the class below, but I am having a little bit of trouble with getting property changes to update if they are assigned internally.  Here is the code in question:

```
class dtAuthHandler {
  private _IsLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  public get IsLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this._IsLoggedIn;
  }
  public set IsLoggedIn(value:boolean)
  {
    this._IsLoggedIn = value;
  }

  Login = () => {
    // More stuff here, internal state, etc.
    this.IsLoggedIn = true;
  }

  Logout = () => {
    // More stuff here, internal state, etc.
    this.IsLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

Here is a simple function that I am using to demonstrate the toggling of the login status.  In the first case, I can set the property directly and the UI updates as expected, so great.  In the second case, I would like to use specific Login()/Logout() functions so that the class can maintain some kind of internal state, talk to servers, etc.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the UI to update when the 'IsLoggedIn' property is set internally.

```
toggleLogin: function () {
  // First Case:
  // Works great, makes sense to me.
  //this.$dtAuth.IsLoggedIn = !this.$dtAuth.IsLoggedIn;


  // Second Case:
  // This updates the state of the class just fine, but the UI doesn't get updated.
  // What to do?
  if (!this.$dtAuth.IsLoggedIn) {
    this.$dtAuth.Login();
  } else {
    this.$dtAuth.Logout();
  }

  // This seems like a hack....
  //this.$forceUpdate();
}
```

My best guess is that 'reactive()' expects the properties to be set externally, and simply isn't aware when they are set internally, that or I am missing something obvious.  What is the best way to handle these types of situations?

For those that are interested, this is how the plugin is setup:

```
export default class dtAuth {

  private authState = new dtAuthHandler();
  install = (app: App) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$dtAuth = reactive(this.authState);
  }
}
```

However, it should be known that I get the same behaviour if the reactive instance is a member of *data* in a class component, e.g.

```
data() : return { auth: reactive(authState) };
```

Comment: Can you show how `this.$dtAuth` is assigned? Where is `reactive()` used? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @tony19 I have updated the question to include the information you requested.  I don't have a full reproduction code available, but what is here ought to be enough to cut+paste on your end if you like.